# Google apps script - Broken for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working in Google apps script and seem to have screwed up one of my for loops. I'm sure that I am missing something trivial here, but I can't seem to spot it.

**Code Snippet:**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var lastRow = sheets[3].getLastRow();
var zw = sheets[3].getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 26).getValues();
for (var j = 0; j < zw.length; ++j) {
    if (zw[j][9] === 'Yes') {
        var masterEmail = [];
        var firstLetterLastName = [];
        var first2Letter = [];
        var masterEmail.push(zw[j][22]);
        var firstLetterLastName.push(zw[j][1].charAt(0).toLowerCase());
        var first2Letter.push(zw[j][1].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + zw[j][1].charAt(1).toLowerCase());
        //The rest of the function follows...
    }
}
```

**What's Not Working:**

The for loop doesn't increment. When running the code in a debugger, var j stays at a value of 0.0, and the rest of the function only runs based of off the values in the 0 position of zw.

**What I need it to do (AKA - How I thought I had written it:)**

The ZW variable is holding a 2 dimensional array of cell values from a Google sheet. I'm looping through that, checking the 9th value of each array entry for a string of "Yes" and then running the rest of the function (for each column with a "Yes") if the condition is true.

I thought I had this working before, but recently had to restructure and optimize some things. Now I'm starting to think I may need to rethink things and use a different loop method. Can anyone educate me?

**Edit: Here's a bit more context as requested:**

```
function menuItem1() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to send emails?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var lastRow = sheets[3].getLastRow();
  var zw = sheets[3].getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 26).getValues();
    if (response === ui.Button.YES) {
      for (var j = 0; j < zw.length; j++) {
        if (zw[j][9] === 'Yes') {
          var firstLetterLastName = [];
          firstLetterLastName.push(zw[j][1].charAt(0).toLowerCase());
          //Other Stuff....
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I have a menu item attached to a simple onOpen, that calls menuItem1(). Calling the function prompts the user with a warning that they are about to send emails, then goes about getting data to assign email addresses based on the contents of the sheets. firstLetterLastName is an example.

I'm still not getting the loop to function, is it because I have it between two if statements? ([Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7zQ2vpmT2ZDn2yHtWZNVck50WCjtpQ-B2-w6jhCEHw/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to the sheet)

Comment: could you show how the spreadsheet data looks like? Because there does not seem to be anything wrong with the for loop you've written.

Comment: I added an edit, does it provide the data you were looking for?

Comment: I made a copy of your spreadsheet, stripped the code out of your `for` loop and `if`clauses and had no problem running your logic. If you aren't getting the expected results, I would focus on the code inside your `for` loop. If you would provide more information on what errors, if any, you're getting that would help us solve your problem.

Comment: The error I'm getting is that [ j ] is staying at 0 instead of incrementing through the data I need it to - zw[j][9]. That corresponds to column...U? in the spreadsheet, which asks the client if they would like to send an email. var zw has all of the expected data (an array of arrays with all cell contents of each row, for each internal array item) I am trying to loop through that, determine whether there is a yes in column 9 of each row, and then run the function based on that. But, since [j] stays at 0, it will only look at one of those rows. Not an "error" per se, I've just done it wrong :)

Comment: I [copied your file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1881M3KXfmYIM4E6mQpKAXpQpmRZNlJGefvWGs7QQl6s/edit?usp=sharing) and started looking at your code. See my edits to the code in my copied file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed it is quite trivial. You have mixed up your increment. You wrote

```
for (var j = 0; j < zw.length; ++j)
```

which means that you do `1 + i` (and we know that at the start `i = 0` which means your value will always be 1) instead of using the usual

```
for (var j = 0; j < zw.length; j++)
```

which would mean that you do `i + 1` and update `i`, so you will get the expected `0 + 1` `1 + 1` etc

**EDIT:**

First, I recommend instead of something like

```
if (responseMir === ui.Button.YES) {
  // Your For loop
```

doing

```
if (responseMir !== ui.Button.YES) {
  return
}
```

and in a similar fashion in the for loop

```
if (zw[j][9] !== 'Yes') {
  break
}
```

It mostly helps increase readability by not including large blocks of code under a single if, when all you want to do is to stop execution.

Your `for` loop gets broken because of the mistake here:

```
teacherEmailMir.push(selValsMir[j][7]);
```

So your loop will go over once. However on the next itteration, you try to push `selValsMir[1][7]` which does not exist. Note that each itteration you have `var selValsMir = [];` **inside** the loop, which means that for every `j` `selValsMir` will always be an **empty** array. So with the following line

```
selValsMir.push([zw[j][0], zw[j][1], zw[j][2], zw[j][3], zw[j][4], zw[j][5], zw[j][7], zw[j][22], zw[j][23], zw[j][24]]);
```

your array will always have `selValsMir.lenght = 1` and `selValsMir[0].length = 10`. So obviously trying to access anything from `selValsMir[1]` will throw you an error and stop the script right there.

I also recommend looking over the `if` statements that look at the first and first 2 letters of the name as I believe you can accomplish the same with less code. Always try to streamline. Consider using `switch()` where you end up using a lot of `else if`

Comment: You are right, thank you :) I'm sure that was part of the problem, but I think I have another issue with it as well. I added an edit above and linked my sheet if you would like to take a look

Comment: @Jensen010 I updated my answer. Seems like I have been working a lot with your particular script so far :D Anyway, try to use more whitespace. Leave a couple of blank lines to break up the code where the logic differs. For example inside the `for` loop, where you have all  your `var` in one block, put an empty line before that block and after it. The readability will immediately increase and the code does not execute any different. **Always use whitespaces**

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. I had it capturing all of the data i needed before switching to the menu to act as the trigger, but some of the things I changed in that process must have messed it up. This will go a long way in figuring that out, and in adapting the whole thing to a more generalized web app (Karl_S comment above) Thank you again for all the helpful answers! :)